# Firefox добавляет блок

Tags: css3, bootstrap, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему на [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/responsive/bottstrap3_logo/) , сделанной на `bootstrap3` в нижней части  экрана `firefox` добавляет [блок](http://prozaik.16mb.com/responsive/bottstrap3_logo/q.png) определённой высоты. в других браузерах этого явления нет.

Comment: у меня нет этого блока (Firefox 12.0)

Comment: Возможно плагин какой-то стоит? У меня в Firefox(25 Linux) все норм.

Comment: Firefox 25, Win7 нет блока, посмотрите что пишет инспектор, кликните на этот блок правой кнопкой мыши и выберите "Исследовать элемент"

Comment: у меня винда. возможно плагин...

Comment: пробовал исследовать элемент. инспектор выделяет тэг html в дереве.
3d-вид вообще ничего не показывает

Comment: зверское распределение цветов. прям доставляет.

Comment: @Arc, человек явно это делает для того, чтоб удобней было верстать, а не потому, что ему такая цветовая гамма нравится ))

Comment: попробуйте у блока `footer_c` изменить высоту в стилях, т.к. когда я делаю высоту меньше `360px;` тоже выскакивает пустота

`.footer_c {
height: 400px; // или больше
background-color: #F5F5F5;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Ну так в `Firefox` всегда стоит `padding` у `body` по умолчанию `10px`. Просто в `CSS` укажите:

```
body {
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: не помогло. добавлял padding: 0 !important; для body и html

Comment: а если все же у `.wrap_c` убрать `margin: 0 auto -360px; padding-bottom: 360px;`

Comment: А у Вас какой Firefox? У меня 25.0 под Windows и все нормально